# Error when training a logistic regression for multiclass classification in Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I'm using this kaggle dataset of news articles (https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rmisra/news-category-dataset), and have 7 classes:

```
def news_data():
    # load embeddings
    with open('embeddings_v1.pkl', "rb") as fIn:
        stored_data = pickle.load(fIn)
        stored_sentences = stored_data['sentences']
        stored_embeddings = stored_data['embeddings']
        x = stored_embeddings
        x = torch.tensor(x).float()
    # load labels    
    with open('.../News_Category_Dataset_v3.json','r') as f:
        jdata = f.read()

    jdata2  = [json.loads(line) for line in jdata.split('\n') if line]
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(jdata2)
    
    label_dict = {'CRIME':0, 'BUSINESS':1, 'SPORTS':2 ,'WEDDINGS':3, 'DIVORCE':4, 'PARENTING':5}
        
    df['label'] = df['category'].map(label_dict).fillna(6).astype(int)

    y = df['label']
    y = torch.tensor(y).float().unsqueeze(1)    

    return split_train_test(x, y)

############# Data summary #############
x_train has shape: torch.Size([167622, 384])
y_train has shape: torch.Size([167622, 1])
x_test has shape: torch.Size([41905, 384])
y_test has shape: torch.Size([41905, 1])
#######################################
```

I am trying to implement a logistic regression model for multiclass classification in pytorch:

```
class LR(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, n_features, n_outputs):
        super(LR, self).__init__()
        self.lr = torch.nn.Linear(n_features, n_outputs)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        out = torch.sigmoid(self.lr(x))
        return out


model = LR(n_features, n_outputs)
# use gradient descent with a learning_rate=0.01
optim = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
# use  Cross Entropy Loss
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()


# instantiate the model
n_features = 384 
n_outputs = 7

# train the model

EPOCHS = 6

def train(model, optim, criterion, x, y, epochs=EPOCHS):
    for e in range(1, epochs + 1):
        optim.zero_grad()
        out = model(x)
        loss = criterion(out, y)
        loss.backward()
        optim.step()
        print(f"Loss at epoch {e}: {loss.data}")
    return model

model = train(model, optim, criterion, x_train, y_train)
```

I run into this error,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 15
     12         print(f"Loss at epoch {e}: {loss.data}")
     13     return model
---> 15 model = train(model, optim, criterion, x_train, y_train)

Cell In[15], line 9, in train(model, optim, criterion, x, y, epochs)
      7 optim.zero_grad()
      8 out = model(x)
----> 9 loss = criterion(out, y)
     10 loss.backward()
     11 optim.step()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py:1174, in CrossEntropyLoss.forward(self, input, target)
   1173 def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
-> 1174     return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
   1175                            ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction,
   1176                            label_smoothing=self.label_smoothing)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py:3029, in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction, label_smoothing)
   3027 if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   3028     reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 3029 return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)

RuntimeError: 0D or 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported
```

What am I doing wrong and need to correct in my code?

Comment: Why are you using "sigmoid" function ? For multi-class problems, "softmax" is the one of the most common choices.

Comment: I think one can use either?  well I just tried softmax() and got TypeError: softmax() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (Tensor), but expected one of:
 * (Tensor input, int dim, torch.dtype dtype, *, Tensor out)
 * (Tensor input, name dim, *, torch.dtype dtype)

Comment: I will reproduce your problem and try to get back asap.

Comment: I have actually taken the code from this example for binomial classification and am trying to adapt it for a multi classification task, https://github.com/OpenMined/TenSEAL/blob/main/tutorials/Tutorial%201%20-%20Training%20and%20Evaluation%20of%20Logistic%20Regression%20on%20Encrypted%20Data.ipynb

Comment: try .flatten() your y_train and y_test.